# Checking if value exists in column other than target row

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

In simplified terms, my spreadsheet is a database with items in column A, and serial numbers in column B.  No two serial numbers can be alike.  One userform has textboxes with items and serial numbers.  For both adding and editing items, the same userform is used.

In order to check if the serial number is unique to the sheet, i used code as follows:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS.Range("b4:b100"), Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i)) > j Then
   MsgBox "serial number " & Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i) & " already exists in database", vbCritical, "Error"
   Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).SetFocus
   Exit sub
End If
```

before adding j, i used 0 to test if any occurrence existed only if I was using Add new.  However, I wanted to check for duplicates also if editing an item.  This creates an error while editing an no changes are made to the serial number but still causing the countif to trip and the sub to exit.

What I tried to do was use the following code to see if the current value matches the textbox item already.

```
IIf WS.Cells(a, 2) = Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).Value, j = 1, j=0
```

"a" refers to the row in which the edited item is.  Basically when editing, a listbox is populated with all items and "a" is called from that listindex

The problem is that even though the cell(a,2) value and the textbox value are the exact same, even showing exactly the same with debug.prints, the if statement comparing them always evaluates as false.  I have tried leaving .value off both, adding .value to either side of the equation, I have even declared variables for each of those two values, made them integers, and compared the two and still shows false.

There might be another way to do this but I want to see if the value of the serial number exists elsewhere in the column excluding the target row it originated from.  If I can do that, then even adding a new item will use the same error checking because the target row will be the first empty row at the end of the list.  Is there a way to do a countif excluding a dynamically changing row?

Edit:
Here is how the data is input into the sheet.

```
With WS.Cells(a, "a")
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).Value
 end with
```

It is only numbers such as "123456" input in the serialnumber textbox.  (no quotation marks)

Comment: The `IIF` function would be used to assign a value to a variable such as `j = IIF(WS.Cells(a, 2) = Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).Value,1, 0)`. The way you are writing it looks to follow the syntax of the `If...ElseIf...Else` statement. You can read about the [IIF function here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function) and the [If...ElseIf...Else statement here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Comment: Sure, i mean technically it should spit out the same results right? If i just used an if then statement to determine j, it should give me the same result.  Either way using your recommendation, and also using a full if..then statement still gives me j=0 even when there is no change and the serial number appears to be the exact same value.  Im not sure if theres a different way to go about tackling the problem and just excluding the origin row where the value was taken from in a counif/match statement.  Is there a way to define a range, then exclude a row? Or a specific part of the range?

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax thing. Although *technically* it should spit out the same results, It wont, because the syntax is wrong.

As you are attempting to assign a value to a worksheet cell, the `IIF` function should be used to return a value, specifically the value you have assigned to the *truepart* argument or the *falsepart* argument.

Per the [`IIF` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function), the **Syntax** is **IIf**(*expr, truepart, falsepart*). So based on if the *expr* (expression) is true or false, the appropriate *truepart* value or *falsepart* value is returned.

It's important to understand that `IIF` is a function that (again per documentation) *Returns one of two parts, depending on the evaluation of an expression.* Because it *returns* the value, you can't assign a value within the function, that's not what it's for.

To use `IIF` in your context, the correct syntax would be:

```
j = IIF(WS.Cells(a, 2) = Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).Value, 1, 0)
```

The key differences are we are assigning the *truepart* value or *falsepart* value to `j` depending on if the evaluation returns true or false. I've also included parentheses around the function which means the return value will be assigned to something (in this case `j`. If you don't include the parentheses the return value is ignored. You can read up more about the use of parentheses with functions (and other thigns) in [Using parentheses in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code).

The `If...Then...Else` statement is a bit different in how it works. ([Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement))

The first line is the evaluation, `If WS.Cells(a, 2) = Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).Value Then`. So far not really any difference in how we evaluate but after this we now assign a *statement* which is another line (or lines) of code to *do something*.

So to rewrite your `IIF` function in an `If...Then...Else` statement:

```
If WS.Cells(a, 2) = Me.Controls("serialnumber" & i).Value Then
    j = 1    'Do this if true
Else
    j = 0    'Do this if false
End if
```

On a new `Worksheet` in a new `Workbook` I tested all of the above syntax with the following two test subs. Feel free to create a new workbook/sheet to see the results in the immediate window based on what value is in cell `C5` at the time you run the code.

```
Sub TestIIFFunction()

Dim j As Long

j = IIf(Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = 1, 1, 0)

Debug.Print j

End Sub
'___________________________________________________________________________________

Sub TestIfThenElseStatement()

Dim j As Long

If Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = 1 Then
    j = 1
Else
    j = 0
End If

Debug.Print j

End Sub
```

The [Visual Basic conceptual topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-conceptual-topics) have some good topics to read about how the code works, what it does and how to use it.

To show visually what I did to test:

### Sheet1 with `=A1` in cell `C5`:

[image: Sheet1 with =A1 in cell C5]

### And the outputs from both the `IIF function` and the `If...Then...Else` statement:

[image: outputs from both the IIF function and the If...Then...Else statement]

Comment: Okay..as I said I tried that..didnt work.. I used the original if then statement and used your j=iif statement and they both give 0 even tho the text box and cell value are exactly the same.  I created a new userform, inserted a text box and a button.  userform activate Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet2.Cells(21, 2).Value. Then commandbutton click Dim j As Integer
    
    j = IIf(Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet2.Cells(21, 2).Value, 1, 0)
    
    Debug.Print Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheet2.Cells(21, 2).Value, j.  Exactly like you said, j is still 0...its not the if  statement its something about the values

Comment: Yes it certainly seems that way - if possible, update your question to incude some information about how the data is put into the sheet/cell in question. Might help work out if it's been converted to an unexpected data type for example (this is common with dates that are input as text, excel doesn't always recognise it as a date value for example).

Comment: Also, have you tried isolating the issue by creating a new blank workbook and testing with dummy data? That's a good way to work out if there is *something* to do with the code or (as we suspect) a data value issue.

Comment: Well yes, thats why I tried a brand new userform, but I'll try a new workbook altogether as well.  I'm thinking its a declaration or value type issue because when I said I tried Dim'ing variables then assigning the textbox value to one, and cell value to the other then inserting those into the if then or iif statement and got the same results.  I just changed the declaration of the textbox variable from variant to integer and it spit out j= 1 as it should..ill start a new workbook and report back

Comment: So I opened a new WB.  New UF, added a textbox and commandbutton.  on the UF code, activate: Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value.  cell(1,1) i typed in 125.  on command button click: Dim j As Integer
    
    j = IIf(Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value, 1, 0)
    
    Debug.Print Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value, j.  J still returns 0.  The debug shows 125 125 0.  They show as the same value but maybe stored as something different? or not the same syntax or something?  Also if there is an easier way to get my result without this if statement.

Comment: I'll do a bit more testing. I didn't realise it was evaluated based on a textbox value on a userform sorry.

Comment: When doing my countif check to see if the value exists, if the range I searched could just exclude the target row.  I assume its not so easy to define a range excluding a specific dynamically changing row?  Then I could remove all this if code anyways.  Although getting to the bottom of my error would be nice, so actually learn from this.

Comment: So on this new WB, I added dim test as integer, test2 as integer.  test=me.textbox1.value, test2=sheet1.cells(1,1).value.  Then did the j=iif(test=test2,1,0) and j comes out as 1.  on the debug print doing both together the test and full names, the full names shows 125 125 0, the test one shows up as 125 125 0.  However, there is a space before the first 125.  So there is some sort of difference, but I dont think you should have to add in extra Dims and such just to get this to work.

Comment: I prefer to pass control values (like textbox values) via a variable than the control reference itself. Someone else might have an explanation as to if you *should* or not or if there is any reason it evaluates differently but it sounds like using variables for both works for you so I'd say that's a win! I did get a space in front of some `Debug.Print` results a few days ago when checking date values in different formats, not sure what it's about though - with my tests with that it didn't affect anything.